# How to Introduce new table

Tags: sql, join

I've 3 tables `Tickets`, `Sales`, `Payments`. Tickets and Payments have `sale_id` in it as a **foreign key**

Ticcekt Table Data

```
TicketID   price   service     sale_id
1          19      City        1
2          19      City        1
3          15      St. Kilda   2
4          36      City        3
```

Sale table data

```
SaleID     sale_time
1          2017-03-01
2          2017-03-01
3          2017-03-01
```

Payment table data

```
PaymentID    amount  sale_id payment_type
1            36      1       cash
2            15      2       eft
3            18      3       cash
4            18      3       eft
```

So Tickets and Payments table may have multiple records against 1 sale. If I have to right query to see the payment amount group by Ticket_table service column and I only have inner join option and also i can't write sub queries, than how i'll introduce a new table to make this work with a simple inner join query.

Currently if i do the inner join it returns me duplicate values. I'm doing this in **Sisense** where my only option is to introduce new tables to fix this.

So what would be the new table which comes in between and make this 1 to 1 relation

**Edit**

Desired result

```
Service   payment_amount
City      72
St.kilda  15
```

Comment: can you post an example of your desired result as I do not understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it's going to duplicate because 3 services CITY has two tickets and 2 sales... therefore to get 72 from 36 amount you sum by grouping the service.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have to use some proprietary database app that doesn't let you write queries, but does let you add tables? Bizarre. If you can't write queries, how does the new table get populated?

Comment: it's a BI tool by sisense, data was imported in it and by default it uses the inner join. Users can then create there own custom tables and write query in the wizard to import data from multiple tables (if they want to)